# Why not add a "IE6 no more" type of warning on SO?

Tags: feature-request, internet-explorer-6

I just saw in the [latest SO blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/browsers-and-screen-size-on-stack-overflow/):

> 7% of [stackoverflow's] overall audience is still on creaky, broken, ancient old IE6.

What do you think about putting an '[IE6 no more](http://www.ie6nomore.com/)' kind of warning on top of the page if the user loads SO (or SF, SU, Meta...) in order to tell them about the suffering that their browsers brings on the web development community?

*Also, SO has some bugs on IE6 (I noticed that the warnings messages are off)*

Of course leave a button "hide forever" since some of them must be forced to use IE6 by their companies.

It would also be interesting to see how the stats evolve next month.

EDIT: I do get that SO doesn't want to alienate people. But I'm not saying "just redirect them to getfirefox.com", it would be a warning that is possible to remove by one click. A lot of websites are doing it

[image]
(image [via](http://www.flickr.com/photos/colbyworld/3024754966/))

I'm surprised that the SO community -so far- is against such an idea.

Comment: well out of 6 answers 5 are against. maybe the wording isn't right (im not native english speaker) but you get the point. feel free to edit my post

Comment: Where's the greater shame, IE6 or Facebook?

Comment: @random Facebook is a website with high traffic that's all.

Comment: No problem!  Thanks for clarifying your meaning.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two reasons why you would still be using IE6:

1. You have to (IT says so, some inhouse app that needs it etc.)
2. You don't get it.

Neither of the two will be changed by a [sevenup](http://code.google.com/p/sevenup) kind of message.

Comment: "You don't get it."

Maybe a warning message would help these users. And I said that it should be possible to hide the message forever if you are forced to use it

Comment: So you want to force me to click something because of a problem that you don't even have?

Comment: I have the problem of spending hours every month fixing IE6 bugs...

Comment: That is because **you** chose to support IE6. Not because **I** made you.

Comment: @marcgg Are you paid for this?

Comment: I would love to be off of IE6 and I agree that it is a horrible browser, but harassing people that have no choice is not the answer.

Comment: That is because *my boss* chose to support IE6

Comment: Ok, then take your problem up with your boss.

Comment: @marcgg: so you agree that your job is to support IE6.

Comment: @devinb: my job is to create websites

Comment: @marcgg: But only for users who you approve of?

Comment: @devinb... seriously? **Every** web designer has concerns with IE 6, and despises it. If you don't, you're not in web design. If his job was to support IE he wouldn't advocate against it unless he wanted to be out of a job.

Comment: @devinb: why so aggressive? I create website for who I'm told to create websites and yeah in some cases if it saves >20% of developing time I'd love to be able to pick the users. In some cases I do (intranet work where we get the users to update their browsers). It is just limitating in term of design and features and I think we would be better off without IE6

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not saying that supporting IE6 is a pain. I'm just saying that if it is sucha a pain that you feel the need to harass your customers, perhaps web dev isn't the proper field for you. It isn't a field that is well known for universal standards compliance even if IE6 were out of the mix altogether.

Comment: @ebgreen IE6 (and 7 but not as much) is really the only browser that makes web development annoying only because it's outdated, otherwise IE8<=>firefox<=>opera<=>safari<=>chrome. I'd guess that you are not a web developer (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I am not a web developer, but I use all of those browsers and I know for a fact that I get a different viewing experience from sites depending on which one I am in. So you can say that they are all the same to develop for, but my experience is that apparently not all developers realize that.

Comment: @marcgg/IanElliot: I am a web developer, and yes, working with IE6 is a pain. But then again, a lot of my clients are a pain, but my paycheque is based on my ability to *deal with these challenges*. If I told my boss that I only wanted to work on easier projects from now on, I imagine he would dock my paycheque to zero.

Comment: Cross platform compatibility will always be painful, but the answer is not to simply exclude those markets. If your client contracts you to support IE6 and you don't want to, then you have three choices. Get a new client, Get a new contract, or Get a new job.

Comment: @devinb: It's actually four choices: develop for IE6 while tring to help making user's habits evolve. If no one does nothing people will keep on using IE6 forever. It's just me being idealistic, but I'd rather do that than do nothing and just wait

Comment: Yay! Rep capped two days in a row. Also, it's kinda cute to be the "host" of a comment discussion thread... You may go on now.

Comment: That doesn't make me happy but it makes sense, and obviously the SO community is against this idea... so accepted it is!

Comment: @marcgg: Fair played. I totally see your point. One day, IE6 will be gone (shortly after COBOL, I guess).

Comment: COBOL will live on after IE6. Of that, I can assure you.

Comment: @devinb I was never advocating this feature request. Personally, it's something I like the idea since I hate IE 6, but would never resort to this. I was simply taken back by the rampant hostility, not even against the idea, but against the person who suggested it.

Comment: Exactly. I don't have another option but to use IE6. So that is why I do.

Comment: @Ian, first of all, my tone may have come across as hostile, but I didn't mean it to. I was simply trying to point out that when it is your job to do something, then complaining about it won't make that go away. I don't honestly believe he should get a new job, I honestly believe he should accept that IE6 is part of his current job. I have no personal issue with him.

Comment: @Ian: Your entire premise is flawed. The conception that obsolete hardware hinders development is absolute gibberish. The fact that IE6 cannot support certain fancy new things does not mean you should stop developing fancy new things. The existence of non-HD tv doesn't make it harder to produce HD stuff. It is an impossibility to make non-HD look like HD, that's true, so why are we trying? And how would you feel if your non-HD tv had a banner on it every time you turned your TV on. And the banner says "You need to buy a new tv!"

Comment: ... People are able to advance their technology, and simply create aspects of their website that are not IE6 accessible. If my program had to be ported to a Commodore64 I would understand that there are portions of it which may not look as good. What I wouldn't do is start a "death to C-64" campaign.

Comment: Bottom line, if a client wants to pay you money to support IE6, then it's *their call*.

Comment: @devinb, it's not flawed at all. There's non trivial time involved in making everything backwards compatible. This time could be **much** better spent improving the technologies for the newer mediums if the old ones didn't have to be supported. Eventually, you **will** have to upgrade because there's no excuse for having outdated technology after a certain amount of time. Movies aren't released on VHS anymore, and TV is broadcast in digital. Get with the times. My argument is far from gibberish. If making something backwards compatible takes time, **it hinders advancement, period.**

Comment: "because there's no excuse for having outdated technology after a certain amount of time.." What about the fact that the new technology won't run my existing app?

Comment: People continue to support IE 6 because they want their services to be accessible to most of the population. Notice how netscape is barely supported *anywhere*? IE 6 is next.

Comment: @EBGreen, what about the fact that your DVD player doesn't play VHS? Technology is always changing, and when you involve yourself with it you need to understand that at some point you *will* have to upgrade. It's illogical to assume that you can purchase something once in your lifetime and expect everything in the future to work on it. You can wait until something reaches critical mass before you switch over, but don't sit there with your 10 year old computer and sue Microsoft when Windows 7 won't run on it.

Comment: I am not making this decision. I guess that is the part that you are not getting. My management is making the decision because there are internal apps that will not run on anything more modern than IE6. To put it in your analogy we only use VHS because we already have all the movies that we want and we don't need to watch any movie that came out since DVDs were available. We just don't need them. But we do need to show people the movies that we already have.

Comment: Well that's strictly an in house decision, and is perfectly acceptable if it remains that way. It is however inevitable that technology will evolve at at some point you will need to change. When this time comes the transition should be made without complaint, because it should have been anticipated since day one.

Comment: @Ian, so your opinion is that 'the transition should be made without complaint'. But you're allowed to complain about those who have not made the transition?

Comment: I thought I've made it clear that I'm not in support of this feature request? It's no secret that I despise IE 6, but I still develop for it, and let users use it as they wish. I entitle myself to criticize the flaws in any platform, old or new; but I avoid criticizing the people who use it.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using StackOverflow or any of the other sites in this trilogy and you are still on IE6, there is likely to be a reason for it and that reason is probably outside of the control of the person using the web browser. Putting a banner in their face telling them to switch is sort of like waving cake in front of a diabetic.

Comment: Even thought I get your point, don't you think that out of these 7% of users there's some that use it just because they don't know? Or maybe people that would go complain to IT asking them to upgrade their browser... which will enventually get things moving?

Comment: It would be impossible for me to say that there aren't some people in the 7% who are blissfully unaware that their browser is ass, but based on the demographics of people who use StackOverflow, SuperUser, and ServerFault, that number has to be absolutely paltry. I again reiterate that those who are "locked in" right now to IE6 probably HAVE talked to their IT department about getting it unblocked (or god forbid they ARE the IT department). If you really think that putting a banner up or some other message saying "you should really switch" is going to help, I will consider you extremely naive.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's going to help per se, it would just give these people another argument toward switching to IE6. But I do believe that there must be some people still using IE6 just because are unaware of the problems linked to this browser (not everyone is a web developer). Then maybe I'm naive, but after a day of fixing a broken layout in IE6 because it doesn't support simple CSS... I don't care :)

Comment: "Hey boss, this website that I waste a lot of my time on tells me that I should switch to IE6 so I can use it better." I'm sure that would go over real well.

Comment: If you'd say it that way, that's for sure

Comment: I'be been arguing to switch off of IE6 for years.  Unfortunately, I work for a company that uses a legacy application that only supports IE6.  We've been working with Microsoft for over a year on workarounds, and still have a ways to go.  Installation of IE8 finally became an option about 6 months ago (we skipped IE7), but a large number of our users can't upgrade until the compatibility issues are solved.  So yes, there is no point in nagging us with what we already know.  (I get around this by using Chrome for all external sites, but most uses aren't lucky enough to be a local admin.)

Answer (score 5):

StackOverflow probably doesn't want to alienate 7% of it's users.

Comment: I'm not saying "stop supporting ie6", I'm saying "put a warning somewhere". It's not that bad, a lot of major websites are doing it

Comment: And I complain to them every chance I get.

Comment: @marcgg "A lot of websites are doing it"... seems to me like there's a gaping flaw in that logic.

Comment: Rich B must be off trying to sneak into women's bathrooms or he would be all over this.

Comment: Maybe he is in a meeting...

Comment: I wish I worked for a company that scheduled meetings in the women's bathrooms.

Comment: I could see someone remoting into a meeting on their laptop from a bathroom stall...that would be a great story some day.

Answer (score 3):

Why do we care?

It doesn't affect us, and like it's been mentioned before, they probably have a reason (IT requirement, legacy app etc...)

It doesn't affect Jeff & the team (they don't bother testing in IE6 any more) and it doesn't affect any of the rest of us (we don't use their computers)

So lets not get in a huff about other people's technology choices (however poor we believe them to be). Remember, we don't have all the information and their decision may in fact be the correct one for their situation.

Comment: It affects the one of us that are web developer and needs to deal with IE6 everyday. The more websites push to get rid of IE6, the fastest we can stop caring about it.

Comment: just do as the SO team has done and stop supporting it. From SO podcast #65 - Atwood: Well, using IE6 is becoming its own penalty because we have rendering problems in IE6 that we're just not going to fix any more, I mean the site will work, but it;s going to look a little weird...

Comment: What's worse: get them to think that SO looks bad because the people that developed it made it that way, or let them know why it's rendering badly and how they could fix it?

Comment: You left out the way that a lot of people will see it "Yell at them for something they have no control over".

Comment: @EBGreen: At work I use IE6.0 **only** for internal apps, everything else, including my own web development, goes trough Firefox first.

Comment: If you are willing to pony up the extra support cost for supporting multiple browsers, I'm sure I could do that at work too.

Answer (score 3):

Man, I don't get you people.  We'll spend all day arguing whether or not LMGTFY is an appropriate answer or simply disrespectful, but on the other hand we're going to suggest telling 7% of the SO users to get a new browser?

A 1972 Ford Pinto is still allowed to drive on the highway, even though it is old, ugly, and pollutes like crazy.  I understand the problems that IE6 creates for web developers, but if we're going to limit what you can use in order to simplify things for the developer, then we might as well just restrict it down to one browser (or go to Flash (or Silverlight!)!).  Yes, it's a reductionist argument, but so be it.

Because there are still many corporations requiring IE6, the solution isn't to shove a banner in their face.  Most of the audience of this site knows that IE6 is a dinosaur.

Answer (score 2):

As developers, our job is to tackle challenges. SO exists because there are many major problems that recur, and we figured we would pool that knowledge. SO exists because we don't have the choice to just "ignore any problems we don't like".

Supporting IE6 is difficult, which is why sites like SO exist. If it was easy, none of us would need any help.

On the other hand, we don't get to choose who our clients are. If some person is working at a company that uses IE6 for various (perfectly valid) reasons, we shouldn't hassle them every time they come here for something that is out of their control.

Anything fancy that won't work in IE, don't provide it in IE6. It seems to me like all the "IE6 must die" people who complain that "coding for IE6 is next to impossible", are completely forgetting that people coded for IE6 for almost 8 years, and they sure as hell did not have the fancy tools that we have.

I say, if someone is using IE6 and wants to visit SO, we should be EXTRA helpful to them, because they're already working against uphill odds.

Answer (score 1):

Does anybody here actually ever worked as a web developer? We're here talking about a huge amount of time wasted to develop for IE6.
But that's not the real issue discussed here.

If you want to make things move forward, you have to take action, why waiting? Warning people that the website won't look as good as it should by using IE6 is just a small step in that direction.
The more warning messages displayed, the faster IT departments will be aware that it's time to upgrade (and hopefully they will upgrade to IE8, not 7).

If you guys are worried about user experience and that extra click one will have to make, why letting people browse a website with a browser not supported without warning users?

One more thing: when Firefox tells you that you should upgrade to the next version nobody's thinking it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea, not as bad as the anti-MS zealots [who won't let you browse their sites if they detect IE](http://www.devin.com/ieblock_howto.shtml), but still bad.

There are a couple of machines we have at work that still need IE6 for legacy reasons, I sometimes browse to the StackOverflow sites from these machines. I don't really need to be reminded every fecking time I hit StackOverflow that I'm running IE6. Of course I bloody know it!

This is preaching to the converted and verging on rudeness.

Comment: I said "a message that you can remove forever". It can be linked to an account or a permanent cookie. It will appear once.

Comment: It's still an annoyance and what happens when I clear my cookies each night?